# Why is there no close reason for 'off topic'?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

I found the next question:

[Any experience in Street Marketing?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/22996/any-experience-in-street-marketing)

However, I wanted to close it since it's about coffee shop marketing, and not related to great outdoors. What reason should I have used to close it? I couldn't find an offtopic because it is unrelated to outdoors reason.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the close reasons, select Off-Topic, and then fill in the specific reason in the field.

It looks like that is what you did - I have completed the close, and deleted the post.

Comment: I don't know how I could have missed that... Thanks for the answer.